# How do you group values in a dataframe to get fewer, more generalized values

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Trying to make a pie plot using a `pd.DataFrame` with 100 values in a column. The output is just one slice per value and I would like to make it so that every 10 or so values have their own slice so it isn't so crowded, and actually gives back some useful data.

I haven't tried much on this matter, seeing as I don't know where to start with it. I do think that maybe the `groupby` function could have a use in this situation.

```py
df.plot.pie(title = title, figsize = (6,6), y = ylabel)
```

This alone is what is giving me the pie chart with 100 slices. I know that there is a way to group them into fewer, as that is part of the goal of this problem, but I haven't the slightest clue as to how.

Comment: Is taking the mean of each 10 consecutive value a good solution to you?

Comment: I would recommend creating bins for your data. This function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html can help with that. Then you could group by bins and have a pie chart on the counts perhaps